# How to collate spaces and apostrophes by COLLATION?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using an arbitrary function to ensure that "foo" and "foo bar" will be before "foobar", eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION std_collate(text) RETURNS text AS $f$
    SELECT regexp_replace($1, E'[ \'\-]', '0', 'g')
$f$ language SQL;
```

but the elegant way is to use `ORDER BY x collate y` (instead `ORDER BY f(x)`)... So, how to do this, perhaps using [`CREATE COLLATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createcollation.html), etc.

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE t (name text);--delete from t;
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('Foo'),('Bar'),('Brasilândia'),('Foo-Bár'),
  ('Brasil Novo'),(E'Foo-B\'ár'),('Foo-B-ár'),('Foo Bar'),('Foo-Bar'),('FooBar');

SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY std_collate(name), name; -- good
SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY 1;  -- bad
```

will generate

```
 -- good
 Bar
 Brasil Novo
 Brasilândia
 Foo
 Foo-B’ár
 Foo-B-ár
 Foo Bar
 Foo-Bar
 Foo-Bár
 FooBar


 -- bad
 Bar
 Brasilândia
 Brasil Novo
 Foo
 FooBar
 Foo Bar
 Foo-Bar
 Foo-Bár
 Foo-B-ár
 Foo-B’ár
```

Comment: @JimJones sorry, you can edit, was a "simultaneous edition bug"...